# TableLayout with a CheckBox move it to one side of the column

Tags: android, checkbox, tablelayout

I have a TableLayout with two columns. Text in the left column and a CheckBox in the right. The CheckBox wont respond to gravity the way I thought it should. It doesnt go to right side of the screen minus the 15dp padding. There still some "padding" keeping it from going all the way to the right.

Other than that, this looks just like I want it.

Is this the most efficient way to do this?

And how can I push the CheckBox around?

![Fun][1]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_weight="75"
            android:text="Label textbox here"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_weight="25"
            android:hint="0.00"
            android:textColor="#000000" >
        </EditText>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_weight="80"
            android:text="Touch for option 2"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_weight="80"
            android:text="Touch for option 3"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_weight="80"
            android:text="Touch for option 4"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_weight="80"
            android:text="Touch for option 5"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_weight="80"
            android:text="Touch for option 6"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_weight="80"
            android:text="Touch for option 7"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_weight="80"
            android:text="Touch for option 8"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_weight="80"
            android:text="Touch for option 9"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the following attributes for TableLayout:

```
android:shrinkColumns
android:stretchColumns
```

and also check the following attributes for the components you use as columns (checkbox and textviews in your case):

```
android:layout_column
android:layout_span
```

Comment: I used android:stretchColumns in the TableLayout and android:layout_gravity="right" in the CheckBox and this solved my issue!....Sorry, I am new so I cant add "This was useful!".

Comment: Also changed android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" in text field. When I added android:layout_gravity="right" it moved the text field a little. Thanks again!